# how to do this in MySql Query?

Tags: mysql

ID
NAME
AMT 
1
Name1
1000
2
Name2
500
3
Name3
3000
4
Name1
5000
5
Name2
2000
6
Name1
3000

consider above table as sample. 
am having a problem in my sql query, Am using like this. 
Select name,amt from sample where amt between 1000 and  5000

it returns all the values in the table between 1000 and  5000, instead 
I want to get  maximum amount record for each name

i.e., 
3 name3 3000
4 name1 5000
5 name2 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select name,amt
from sample
where amt between 1000 and 5000
ORDER BY amt DESC
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: I would use this query then deep - otherwise as described my query returns the wrong ID.

Simply add id to the list of columns returned

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    name,MAX(amt) AS amt
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    amt BETWEEN 1000 and 5000 
GROUP BY name
```

Here you're grouping by the name column, and retrieving the maximum value of the column 'amt' within that GROUP, for all of the rows where amt is between 1000 and 5000. This query is untested, but is simple enough - I believe it should work.

Comment: Fair enough, looks like Coronatus got it. My bad

Comment: hey thanks seidr, your query working... my innodb issue.. its working

Comment: hai i want to get id field also when i add id into that query, it shows the id wrongly... can u plz update id field into the query ???