# Mysql Query problem?

Tags: mysql

```
ID NAME AMT 
1 Name1 1000 
2 Name2 500
3 Name3 3000
4 Name1 5000
5 Name2 2000
6 Name1 3000
```

consider above table as sample.

am having a problem in my sql query, Am using like this.

```
Select name,amt from sample where amt between 1000 and 5000
```

it returns all the values in the table between 1000 and 5000, instead I want to get maximum amount record for each name

i.e.,

```
3 name3 3000
4 name1 5000
5 name2 2000
```

Comment: You should probably accept some answers.

Comment: Opening a new query for the very same question you asked recently is not the way to go about things.

Comment: Duplicate of question you asked 3 hours ago.

Comment: hai seidr sorry, am not asking the same question again, actaully the query u posted is worked well, but later i saw the id is coming wrongly, so i asked this question again, but i closed that thread alreadi. can u tel how to get the id also in that query??

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551798/how-to-do-this-in-mysql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need ONE of the ids that contains the MAX(amt), then this will do the trick:

```
SELECT id, name, MAX(amt)
FROM sample
WHERE amt BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
GROUP BY name;
```

If you need all the ids, then it gets more complicated. Two queries are required, plus a temporary table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE maxamts
    SELECT name AS maxname, MAX(amt) AS maxamt
    FROM sample
    WHERE amt BETWEEN 1000 AND 5000
    GROUP BY maxname;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id), maxname AS name, maxamt AS amt
FROM maxamts
LEFT JOIN sample ON ((maxname = sample.name) AND (maxamt = amt))
GROUP BY maxname;
```

In short: Create a temporary table from the query that finds each name/max(amt) pair, then use that temporary table to join back on the original table and pull out the IDs matching the name/amount combinations.

Just remember that group_concat is by default limited to 1,024 characters, (`show variables like '%group_concat%'` to see the max length on your server), so if you've got a large dataset, increase that limit, or remove the group_concat and group by from the second query and parse the information in your application.

Comment: marc, when i worked in your query, the mysql returns the group_concat as system.Byte[] like in my database.. am using c#.net for retrieving mysql data ????

Comment: Haven't the foggiest. Never worked with C# before. Perhaps the ODBC driver (or whatever C# uses) is getting confused by the function-call naming of the field. Try changing it to `GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS ids` or maybe even `CAST(GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS char) AS ids`.

Comment: Marc, its working fine, but when i run the code again,its telling the temp table exists already, is there any way to clear that table after my execution??

Comment: `DROP TABLE maxamts` after you're done. Temporary tables are dropped automatically when you disconnect from the DB, but if you keep the connection going, you'll have to drop it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
select name, max(amt) from sample group by name
```

You'll have problems getting the id, though, as there may be more than one.

Comment: Is your "amt" unique? If it's not there's no single "corresponding id field".

Answer (score 1):

you should group by NAME:

```
SELECT `name`,MAX(amt) from sample GROUP BY `name` where amt between 1000 and 5000
```

Comment: i need to get corresponding id also

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, amt from sample where amt = (select max(amt) from sample)
```

that should return all records that have the max amt from the sample table

edit:

```
select id, name, amt 
from sample 
where amt = (
  select max(amt) 
  from sample 
  where amt between 1000 and 5000)
```

this query will return all records that have an amount equal to the max amount between 1000 and 5000

Comment: where i can place this condition  (between 1000 and 5000)

Comment: Added a new query for you to look at

Comment: there is only one row that contains the max amount between 1000 and 5000 in your sample data.